# Should a function that returns something be named as an accessor (getSomething)?

Tags: clean-code, functions

I understand accessors have to do with OOP. For other languages such as C, imagine you have a function that given 2 numbers returns their sum. Should you name it `getSum()` or `sum()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I have a function that computes a sum, I would simply call it `sum` (a verb) whether I'm working in a procedural or an object-oriented language.

If I'm retrieving a property named `sum` (a noun), I would follow the conventions for that specific language for doing so, for example, `get_sum()` in C, `getSum()` in Java or a `Sum` property in C#.

**Clarification:** This does not mean that a property accessor cannot perform any computation. However, if the function is intended to perform a computation rather than expose a (computed) property value, it shouldn't be modeled like a property.

Comment: Sorry, could you explain what do you mean by retrieving a property?

Comment: @DuarteArribas: By property, I mean an attribute of an object, such as color or size. "Sum" is unlikely to be a property, unless you are modeling some kind of statistical object that has properties such as sum, average etc.

Comment: I would also add that I expect `getBlah` type functions to just return a piece of data that already exists, and should **never** fail nor be more than just a few cpu cycles in cost. Otherwise, if computation or other resources need to be used, it should have a different style name.

Comment: If you are accessing a property use a noun. such as `result`, `colour`, `transcript`. When you a doing something use a verb: `sum`, `colourise`, `write`.

Comment: This advice breaks the *Uniform Access Principle*. A client *must not know* and must not be able to know whether a value was computed or retrieved.

Comment: Elaborating on @Jorg comment, if the calculation is something like area, e.g. using the height and width, it should be named according to "getter" style for your language, e.g. `myShape.getArea()` in Java.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: I've clarified my answer, I was simply talking about modeling the intent of the API, I'm not against performing computation in a "getter".

Comment: @Kain0_0 unfortuantely lots of words in English are verbs and nouns e.g. sum

Answer (score 2):

Some functions are queries asking for results without asking for change.

But other "functions" are requests for change returning a result of success or failure, or sometimes (a reference to) the item created.

The former are just getters in some sense, while the latter are not despite returning a value.

Answer (score 0):

a getter I'd expect to be a funtion () -> T i.e. takes no argument and returns something (`Supplier<T>` in Java)

sum as a function does not have this signiture, it would have (int, int) -> int or similar. so no I would not call this getSum but sum.